# Convert list of tuples to a dictionary using as key part of each tuple

Tags: python

How can this be done the python way :)

```
results = [(1,2,3), (2,5,6), (7,8,9)] 
results_set = {}
for r in results:
    results_set[(r[0], r[1])] = r[2]
return results_set
```

Comment: This is fine. The only improvement: use `for x, y, z in results:` then you can say `results_set[x,y] = z`

Comment: This isn't a set; it's a dictionary.

Comment: @kaya3 you are correct; updated the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
results = [(1,2,3), (2,5,6), (7,8,9)] 

print({(x, y) : z for x, y, z in results})
```

**Output**

```
{(1, 2): 3, (2, 5): 6, (7, 8): 9}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterable unpacking:

```
lst = [(1,2,3), (2,5,6), (7,8,9)]

{tuple(k): v for *k, v in lst}
# {(1, 2): 3, (2, 5): 6, (7, 8): 9}
```